# When I enter Ctrl+Z to finish the loop below, I get the null string in variable z. Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

The buffer `z[]` gets the null character in its first byte when the EOF (Ctrl+Z in Windows) is entered to finish the loop. Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char z[10];
    while( cin >> z ) cout << z << '\n';

    if( cin.eof() ) cout << z << "End of input\n";
}
```

This doesn't happen below, i.e., `z` will keep the last character read from the keyboard.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char z;
    while( cin >> z ) cout << z << '\n';

    if( cin.eof() ) cout << z << "End of input\n";
}
```

Comment: So, did you get your answer?

Answer (score 5):

**Because the standard says so!**

You're giving the stream what looks like a C-string buffer. Even if the extraction results in a failure bit being set, it wants to terminate what it put in that buffer (in this case, the empty string).

Here's the proof, from the definition of `template<class charT, class traits>
basic_istream<charT,traits>& operator>>(basic_istream<charT,traits>& in,
charT* s)`:

> `[C++11: 27.7.2.2.3/8]`: **Characters are extracted and stored until any of the following occurs:**
>
> - `n-1` characters are stored;
> - **end of file occurs on the input sequence;**
> - `ct.is(ct.space,c)` is true for the next available input character `c`, where `ct` is `use_facet<ctype<charT> >(in.getloc())`.
>
> `[C++11: 27.7.2.2.3/9]:` **`operator>>` then stores a null byte (`charT()`) in the next position, which may be the first position if no characters were extracted.**

It bears mentioning that this is the case for extraction into a `std::string`, too:

> `[C++11: 21.4.8.9/1]:` *Effects:* Behaves as a formatted input function (27.7.2.2.1). After constructing a sentry object, if the sentry converts to true, **calls `str.erase()` and then extracts characters from `is`** and appends them to `str` as if by calling `str.append(1,c)`. If `is.width()` is greater than zero, the maximum number n of characters appended is `is.width()`; otherwise n is `str.max_size()`. **Characters are extracted and appended until any of the following occurs:**
>
> - `n` characters are stored;
> - **end-of-file occurs on the input sequence;**
> - `isspace(c,is.getloc())` is `true` for the next available input character `c`

That is, for both a `char` buffer and a `std::string`, if the stream is in a valid state immediately before the extraction, even if the extraction pulls out zero characters before reaching EOF, your input object will be "cleared".

No such rule exists for a single `char`:

> `[C++11: 27.7.2.2.3/12]:` *Effects:* Behaves like a formatted input member (as described in 27.7.2.2.1) of `in`. After a sentry object is constructed a character is extracted from `in`, if one is available, and stored in `c`. Otherwise, the function calls `in.setstate(failbit)`.

The original value is left unperturbed if there weren't a new one to take its place.